# how do I center this image, without touching the HTML

Tags: css

Can anyone tell me how I can center the image thumbnail relative to the large image?

I can only edit the css, as I am using a proprietary cart solution: http://cailinshea.com/#ecwid:category=1200474&mode=product&product=4321711

Additionally; I can write PHP - but haven't touched Javascript in years... is there a better cart solution that I could implement with Wordpress easily? I am finding it increasingly difficult to customize the design of this wordpress site with ecwid cart.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: lol yeah, I have to work with the ecwid cart - and completely gave up on making the code clean...

not to mention, the theme, and wordpress play a role as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`div.ecwid-productBrowser-details-GalleryPanel-imageContainer` needs to be centered within `div.ecwid-productBrowser-details-GalleryPanel`.  It's currently set to `float: left`, remove that and add:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

That did the trick in Chrome's dev tools.

I really like [Enstore](http://www.enstore.com/), but it's not Wordpress. But yeah, this cart plugin has really ugly html...

Comment: Is enstore completely open source? Do I have to pay to unlock common features?

I've been working on my own store app in PHP, but it won't be finished for a few months

Comment: this worked, but now http://cailinshea.com/#ecwid:category=1200474&mode=product&product=4321698 is displaying images vertically (when there is more than 1 thumbnail)

Comment: No, it's proprietary, but free right now in beta. I like the clean look of it. But if you can write your own, you might as well do that, rather than giving someone else money.

Comment: Look's fine in Chrome. Must be a Firefox thing.

Comment: The page with the single thumbnail works - but when it has more than one thumnail - like http://bit.ly/olkzlU - it makes them stack vertically (we need horizontal)

Answer (score 0):

following should work:

```
#ecwid_body div.ecwid-productBrowser-details-GalleryPanel-imageContainer{
    margin:0 auto !important;
    float:none !important;
}

.ecwid-productBrowser-details-GalleryPanel > div:first-child{
    margin:0 auto !important;
}
```